# Typescript and Gulp: loop through array of Angular routes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, gulp

I am using Gulp to generate a sitemap for an Angular project by importing the routes arrays from my routing modules. Here's an example of a Route object:

```
{
 path: 'about', 
 component: AboutUsComponent,
 pathMatch: 'full',
 resolve: [DataResolverService]
}
```

The only member I need is **path**, which is *always* a string. The problem is that I am getting errors such as
`ReferenceError: Event is not defined` or
`reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators` because my gulpfile is trying to instantiate the component classes and my route guard service classes. Is there any way to prevent this?

Bonus if I can check the canActivate array for an instance of `LoginPageGuardService`, in the following route for example:

```
{
  path: 'customer-portal/login',
  loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule',
  canActivate: [LocationGuardService, LoginPageGuardService],
  resolve: [DataResolverService]
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
for(let route of websiteRoutes) {
    urls.push({url: `/${route.path}/`});
}
```

and

```
for(let i=0; i<websiteRoutes.length; i++) {
    urls.push({url: `/${websiteRoutes[i].path}/`});
}
```

Importing the arrays of routes is not causing an issue, but as soon as I have a for loop indexing the arrays, Gulp errors out.

**Update:**
I am currently exporting/importing the routes like so:

`export const websiteRoutes: Routes = [...];`

`import { websiteRoutes } from './path/to/other/file';`